# SAS macro changing variable type

Tags: variables, types, macros, sas

I am building macro whitch generates empty table by my own structure from other table. How to change variable type?

example from my code:

```
`%let vname = %sysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,%sysfunc(varnum(&dsid,varName))));
%let vtype = %sysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,%sysfunc(varnum(&dsid,varType))));
%let vformat = %sysfunc(getvarc(&dsid,%sysfunc(varnum(&dsid,varFormat))));

%if &vtype = C %then %do;
    &vname=putc(&vname,&vformat);
%end;`
```

And it's not working... Any other ideas how to change var type?

Answer (score 1):

You should be clear whether you just need empty table with some columns in a changed data type (definition) or you'd also like to actually convert the data content/values. First case should be much easier.
Because currently in

```
&vname=putc(&vname,&vformat);
```

you're trying to convert the data values, not the definition. The definition of variable is not changed and in data step actually can't be changed.
You can't create a "new" variable when there's still the original variable present ***inside*** your data step with same name.

In data step, you'd need to define new variables with different names inside data step and use RENAME (new to to original names) and DROP (original names) options on output dataset to end up with same name in output dataset (I can clarify if needed).

For just defining the empty table, PROC SQL could be easier, you need to create a code like:

```
proc sql;
create table lib.table (
orig_var1 type format informat label
, orig_var2 NEWTYPE format informat label
, ...
);
quit;
```

which can be built from dictionary.columns. This is also easier to keep original order of variables (not so easy in data step).
You just need to take care to define appropriate length for character variables based on the length of the format used if you'd like to store formatted value of numeric variable in new character variable.